# How to layout view correctly after stroke of background drawable changed?

Tags: android, android-layout

**What I have:**

I have a `LinearLayout` which contains `Views` with a background `Drawable` (rectangular shape with rounded corners and a stroke). They act as color selection buttons. Initially the first button has a background with a thicker stroke (4px instead of 1px). Everything is nice (see left side of picture below).

**What I want:**

However, when I press such a button, I want to remove the thick stroke from the previously selected button and apply it to the actual button. I try it the following way (only a snippet):

```
// get layout
LinearLayout favoriteColorsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.favoriteColorsLayout);

// get view at old position, update stroke, invalidate
View view = favoriteColorsLayout.getChildAt(selectedColorButton);
GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable) view.getBackground();
drawable.setStroke(1, Color.parseColor("#bbbbbb"));
view.invalidate(); // do I need this?

// also update stroke of new view
..

// re-layout
favoriteColorsLayout.requestLayout(); // do I need this?
```

**What I see:**

And indeed the thicker stroke is moved but unfortunately the layout is wrong afterwards! The colored background of buttons 2-4 should become thinner when the stroke surrounding them gets thicker so that they are still fitting into the containing layout but this does not happen (see right side of picture below). Instead the stroke is partially cut off (because otherwise it would be drawn outside the bounds of the View). This is not a desired effect.

**What do I have to do to get the desired effect instead?**
I know how many buttons of which color I have only at runtime, so I would prefer a programmatic solution.

Actually I'm beginning to think it could be an Android bug since drawing the stroke outside the borders per default is surely not desired behavior. I see the effect on the emulator and API level 23 as well as my old phone with API level 11.

[image]

A bit of layout xml. The linear layout (Views are added programmatically):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/favoriteColorsLayout"></LinearLayout>
```

The button Views:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<View xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/color_selection_button_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/color_selection_button_size"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/color_selection_button_margin"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/color_selection_cell_background">
</View>
```

The buttons background drawable (color_selection_cell_background.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">

    <stroke
        android:width="1px"
        android:color="#bbbbbb"/>

    <corners
        android:radius="5px" />

    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:centerX="0.5"
        android:centerY="0.5"
        android:startColor="#aaaaaa"
        android:endColor="#bbbbbb"
        android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Can you post the layout XML?

Comment: @JimRhodes Sure. Is attached.

Comment: As a comment: I really want a programmatic solution since I don't know the number or gradient color of each button before running.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you are doing it in code but why not have two drawables and change those?

**button_blue_selected.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    android:shape="rectangle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <solid android:color="@color/blue_500" />
    <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="@color/grey_500" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

**button_blue_unselected.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    android:shape="rectangle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <solid android:color="@color/blue_500" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/grey_500" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

Then update the background drawable in your code:

```
View view = favoriteColorsLayout.getChildAt(selectedColorButton);
view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_blue_selected);
```

Or even better you could use a third drawable with state so you didn't need to update it directly in code:

**button_blue.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_blue_selected" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_blue_unselected" />
</selector>
```

And then:

```
view.setSelected(true);
```

Comment: I do parts in code because the number of buttons can vary and for only a single property it seemed like the easier way. Thanks for the answer, I'll need a bit of time to check it.

Comment: @Trilarion - Makes sense. You still might be able to use the third drawable with state to handle changing the background automatically with the `setSelected` method.

Comment: I checked your code and it works in principle and is also a nice example but I cannot accept it as solution because in my case I don't know the number of fill color of each Drawable in advance and therefore must do it programmatically. Unfortunately I still haven't managed that and nobody else here too. It may be an Android bug.